# Solve second order differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Equation:** $$ y'' +6y' +9y = x^2-x+e^{-3x} $$

Please correct this method of solving. - How can I better comment what I'm doing? And I'm not sure if my method of solving this equation is correct. 
$$--------------------------------------$$

First we solve the associated second order linear homogenous ordinary differential equation.

$$ y'' + 6y'+9y = 0  $$

We substitute: $y=e^{rx}$

$$r^2+6r+9=0 $$

$$r_0 = -3$$

$$y=y_0 + Ae^{-3x}+Bxe^{-3x} \tag{*}$$ 
$A$ and $B$ are constants.

Secondly we find solution of the non-homogenous ordinary differential equation:

**CASE 1**

$$y''+6y'+9y=x^2-x$$

We can assumpt that solution has a form:

$$ y=ax^2+bx+c$$
$$ =>y' =2ax+b $$
$$ =>y'' =2a $$

$$y''+6y'+9y=x^2-x$$

We put this functions to equation and we get:$a=\frac{1}{9} , b=\frac{-7}{27} c=\frac{-4}{27} $

So we get $$y= \frac{1}{9}x^2 -\frac{7}{27}x- \frac{4}{27} $$

**CASE2**

$$ y''+6y'+9y = e^{-3x}$$

We use variation of parameters method:

$$y=f(x)e^{-3x} \tag{1} $$

$$ y' = f'e^{-3x} -3fe^{-3x}$$

$$ y'' = f''e^{-3x}-6f'e^{-3x}+9fe^{-3x}$$

We put those funcions to equation $(1)$

$$f'' e^{-3x} =e^{-3x} $$

$$f'' =1$$

So we have to find any function which satisfies condition $f'' =1$

So $f=\frac{x^2}{2} +5$

From CASE1, CASE2 and (*) the solution of equation: $ y'' +6y' +9y = x^2-x+e^{-3x} $ is:
$$y=(\frac{x^2}{2} +5)e^{-3x}+ \frac{1}{9}x^2 -\frac{7}{27}x- \frac{4}{27} + Ae^{-3x}+Bxe^{-3x}$$ $A$ and $B$ are constants.

$$... $$

Comment: What is $y_0$ in the * equation?

Comment: A simpler method for case 2 is to observe that $e^{-3x}$ has the same form as the homogeneous solution, therefore the particular solution has the form $y_p = Cx^2e^{-3x} $

Comment: By $y_0$ I mean all non-homogenous solution of the main equation.

Comment: @Dylan It's strange for me. I mean you are looking for the solutions for the homogeneous form, and that's only $Ae^{-3x}+Bxe^{-3x}$ And why did you put the +5 in the f? $5e^{-3x}+Ae^{-3x}=Ae^{-3x}$

Comment: Now I see @grzegorzs

Comment: I put +5 in f because I wanted to show that it can be really any function. So particulary $\frac{x^2}{2} +5 $ is also good. I wasn't sure about that

Comment: Could you explain me this simpler solution of case2? I don't catch it.

Comment: @grzegorzs You need a specific solution for case 2. You don’t need +5, since you already have $Ae^{-3x}$ in the homogeneous solution. Here, $A$ is the number which can be chosen by initial value condition.